# how to show value from table as selected value in dropdown in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on an ecommerce project in php. Everthing is completed except one thing "cart.php". In this "Shopping cart" following items are shown in a table : Product Image, Quantity and Price. In the Quantity column there is a dropdown which is populated with numbers from 1 to 10.

Here, I want to "**show the product quantity that is stored in the table to be shown as a selected quantity**" of the dropdown. How will I achieve this ?

Following is my code :

```
$pickrecs = "SELECT t_ordid, DATE_FORMAT(tord_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as label_date, file_path, file_name, lbl_qty FROM ord where uid = '{$getid}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $pickrecs); ?>
    <table id='display'>
      <thead>
         <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Creation&nbsp;Date</th>
        <th>Labels</th>
        <th>Total&nbsp;Price (&nbsp;&nbsp;)</th>
        <th></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $row["t_ordid"] ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row['file_path'] ?>" alt="" style="width:61px; height:54px" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["label_date"] ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php
                 $pickrecs = "SELECT r.rt_qty, r.rt_cost FROM rm as r join fy as f on r.fin_yr = f.fyear where f.status='A'";
                 $rtlist = mysqli_query($connection, $pickrecs); 
                 echo "<select id='rtcrt' name='rtcrt' value='' class='rdd'>";
                   while($rtlistarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtlist)){ 
                 //echo "<option value = $rtlistarr[rt_qty]>$rtlistarr[rt_qty]</option>";
                 echo "<option value = $row[lbl_qty]>$rtlistarr[rt_qty]</option>";
                   }
                 echo "</select>";
              ?>
              <?php echo $_POST['rtcrt'] = $row['lbl_qty'] ?>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="i-cost" value="5.95" readonly class="icost"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Shopping Cart 
[Snapshot of Shopping Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pImI8.jpg)

Comment: Is there any error with the current code?

Comment: I can't see where is the quantity field in your code!

Comment: Anyway you can simply loop all the options 1 > 10 and make a condition when the number of the option in the loop matches the `qty` add `selected` to the `<option>`